# Pre-trained XGBoost model does not reproduce results if loaded from file

Tags: python, save, load, xgboost

I use XGBoostClassifier (XGBoost version 1.6.0) for a simple binary classification model in Google Colab. I save the model into file for further use. Within the same session, the model loaded from file reproduces results well on validation set. But, if the session is over and I connect to Colab from scratch, the same model from the same file shows way worse results on the same validation set, and needs to be trained again to be reproduced.
Tried three different ways to save and load model:

- native

```
xgb_model.save_model('xgb_native_save.model')
```

- joblib

```
joblib.dump(xgb_model, 'xgb_joblib.model')
```

- pickle

```
with open('xgb_pickle.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(xgb_model,f)
```

Same result with all three methods: the results on validation set are not even close to those the model showed before saving to file.
Random_state is fixed.
Any thoughts on where might the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

I find the same issue with tree based models for binary classification (XGBoost, LightGBM, ...)

When you restart the kernel and load the saved model, the order of the variables inside the booster changes.

This is how I solved it (xgboost):

```
lst_vars_in_model = model.get_booster().feature_names

model.predict_proba(df[lst_vars_in_model])
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. How come this is not documented?